# Normalizing a column of data by another entry in a specific row for R

Tags: r

So I have a dataset (this is a toy example)

```
dates <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
dates2 <- c(-1,1,2,-1,1,2, -1, 2,3) 
amt <- c(1000, 100, 100, 1000, 100, 100, 1000, 100, 100)

dat <- cbind(dates, dates2, amt)
```

And for dataframe dat, I need to divide amt, by itself but only where dates2 is = -1.  So I'd get an output dataframe like:

```
clean
1 1 0.10  (IE 100 / 1000, for row 2)
1 2 0.10
2 1 0.10
2 2 0.10
3 2 0.10
3 3 0.10
```

Does someone know an easy way to tackle this?  (My brain is like mush right now)

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting from the input to the output: `I need to divide amt, by itself but only where dates2 is = -1.` Wouldn't dividing `amt` by itself get `1`? And where does the `c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3)` column come from?

Comment: Ah yes, I see where its not clear.

All rows, excluding those where dates2 = -1.
In the output set, amt will be divided by the amt where dates2 = -1 and dates matches the rows (think like a self join)

So row 2 where date = 1 and date2 =1, 100 would be divided by 1000 from row date=1 and date2=-1.  

Does that make sense?

Comment: The `clean` object appears to be a dataframe but the `dat` object is a matrix. Was that intentional?

Comment: no, clean is meant to be a dataframe.  Just typed it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update:

Nice, one liner, compliments of @Arun (in the comments below):

```
DT[, amt := { amt <- amt/amt[dates2 == -1] }, by=dates][dates2 != -1]
```

or, more succinctly, still:

```
DT[, amt := amt/amt[dates2 == -1], by=dates][dates2 != -1]
```

---

#### Original Answer:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(dat, key="dates")

# grab "-1" rows, at same time, change col name for simplicity
DT.dates2 <- setnames(DT[dates2==(-1)], "amt", "amt.d")

# remove rows where dates2 == -1
DT <- DT[dates2 != -1] 

# divide as required
DT[DT[dates==dates2][DT.dates2], amt := amt / amt.d]
```

#### Results:

```
DT 

   dates dates2 amt
1:     1      1 0.1
2:     1      2 0.1
3:     2      1 0.1
4:     2      2 0.1
5:     3      2 0.1
6:     3      3 0.1
>
```

Comment: (+1) nice solution. Alternatively it could also be done without splitting the data.table like this I think: `DT[, amt := { amt <- amt/amt[dates2 == -1] }, by=dates][dates2 != -1]`

Comment: @Arun, thanks, and for the suggestion as well!   In fact, I think we can go even more cleaner still.   Edited answer

Comment: This worked really well for data.table 1.8.1.  However, I only had 1.7 on my box so I had to do (something like):
cbind( DT[dates2 != -1], DT[, amt/amt[dates2 == -1], by=dates][dates2 != -1]

Answer (score 1):

```
 by(dat, dat[1], FUN= function(dfm) {
        dfm[ dfm$dates2 != -1, 3] <-dfm[ dfm$dates2!= -1, 3]/dfm[ dfm$dates2== -1, 3]
        return(dfm[ dfm$dates2 !=-1 ,])  } )
dates: 1
  dates dates2 amt
2     1      1 0.1
3     1      2 0.1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dates: 2
  dates dates2 amt
5     2      1 0.1
6     2      2 0.1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dates: 3
  dates dates2 amt
8     3      2 0.1
9     3      3 0.1
```

You can use `do.call(rbind, ...)` if you want them as a dataframe again.